# Binding the checked state of a togglebutton to the visibility of a usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a way of doing this now using code-behind and changing visibility of 'panels' , but I wonder if this can be done in a straight xaml way?

Comment: Have you tried datatriggers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to bind this using `ElementName`, along with an `IValueConverter` that converts true/false to Visibility:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <UserControl Visibility="{Binding ElementName=toggle,
                                      Path=IsChecked,
                                      Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" 
    />
    <ToggleButton x:Name="toggle" />
</Grid>
```

And the converter:

```
public class BoolToVisibilityConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var isChecked = (bool)value;
        return isChecked ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: in `<local:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Name="BoolToVisibilityConverter" />`, should `x:Name` or `x:Key` be used? What is the difference?

Comment: @Serge should be `x:Key` actually.  `x:Key` is for use in a `ResourceDictionary`, and `x:Name` is for regular XAML elements.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can do it like below.. you can have both your `usercontrol` and `togglebutton` as the content of a parent `Contentcontrol` and use `DataTemplate` triggers to set visibility of user control depending on checked status of `ToggleButton`

```
       <ContentControl>
            <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <local:myusercontrol  x:Name="control"/>

                        <ToggleButton Content="click" x:Name="toggleBtn"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="false"  SourceName="toggleBtn">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="control"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true" SourceName="toggleBtn">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="control"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
        </ContentControl>
```